# mpirun: error while loading shared libraries: libopen-rte.so.12:

Tags: 16.04, mpi

I have installed `openmpi-bin` and `openmpi-common`, and I get the following error when I run either `mpirun` or `mpiexec`:

```
mpirun: error while loading shared libraries: libopen-rte.so.12
```

As I checked, this library should be a part of the `openmpi-bin` (or common), but no matter how many times I try to reinstall it i get the same error.

Also no libraries like `lib*-rte.*` can be found at `/usr/lib`, and i cant find anything similar in other lib folders neither.

What should I do?

Comment: Did you install `openmpi-bin` and `openmpi-common` fromthe standard repositories? What does `apt-cache policy libopenmpi1.10` say?

Comment: @steeldriver `$ apt-cache policy libopenmpi1.10
libopenmpi1.10:
  Installed: 1.10.2-8ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.10.2-8ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.10.2-8ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My system says that this library comes from the package `libopenmpi1.10`. So you will need to install this.

```
$ find /usr/lib -name *libopen-rte*
/usr/lib/libopen-rte.so
/usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libopen-rte.so
/usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libopen-rte.so.12.0.2
/usr/lib/libopen-rte.so.12.0.2
/usr/lib/libopen-rte.so.12
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/libopen-rte.so.12
libopenmpi1.10: /usr/lib/libopen-rte.so.12
```

Comment: Reinstalling `libopenmpi1.10` solved it! Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You may just need to run this command to link the appropriate libraries:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: what does it do?

Comment: ldconfig creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/lib and /usr/lib). look here for many informations https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-ldconfig

Comment: @Compiii Could you please [edit] your answer and provide the above comment there?